# Python Mechanize Module Encryption

Tags: python, encryption, https, mechanize, mechanize-python

If I am using a python script with mechanize to fill out forms on websites (such as login information) should I be worried about encryption? Is there anything I need/could do to ensure that the password sent is encrypted? (Or is this even necessary? Is filling out a form with mechanize equivalent to filling out a form with a standard web browser and therefore there I am not actually "sending" anything (ie. its up to the website to use https)).

Thanks!
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's exactly the same as using a web browser -- you should use the same judgement as to whether you want to enter your username and password.

Comment: With the added risk of storing the password if he automates that portion.